# Parse query with a wherekey on a pointed to object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I am trying to create a query where I can check if the value of an object pointed to meets a certain requirement. Example I have a class called rooms, each room object has a pointer to a post object. I want to check wherekey updatedAt of the post object when getting rooms.

I have tried doing this `query.whereKey("post.updatedAt", greaterThan: timeThen!)`

but it returns empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relational query so you have to make a query for posts first

```
let postsQuery = PFQuery(className:"Post")
query.whereKey("updatedAt", greaterThan: timeThen!)
```

and then compose the query with the `postsQuery` like this:

```
query.whereKey("post", matchesQuery query: postsQuery)
```

here is the [link](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-queries) for the parse guide.